# problemas con condicion if y funciones

Tags: javascript, html, funciones

estoy teniendo un par de problemas con la condicion if, les dejo el codigo:

```js
// Variables
var serieButton = document.getElementById("serieButton");
var parallelButton = document.getElementById("parallelButton");
var realSerieZ1 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
var imaginarySerieZ1 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1];
var realSerieZ2 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[2];
var imaginarySerieZ2 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[3];
var moduleSerieZ1 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[4];
var phaseSerieZ1 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[5];
var moduleSerieZ2 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[6];
var phaseSerieZ2 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[7];
var resultRealSerie = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[9];
var resultImaginarySerie = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[10];
var resultModuleSerie = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[11];
var resultPhaseSerie = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[12];

// Conversor de angulos
Math.radiansToDegrees = function(radians) {
    return radians * 180 / Math.PI;
};

// Calculadora
var sumSerieReIm = function(){
    var realTotal = realSerieZ1.valueAsNumber + realSerieZ2.valueAsNumber;
    var imaginaryTotal = imaginarySerieZ1.valueAsNumber + imaginarySerieZ2.valueAsNumber;
    var totalModule = Math.hypot(realTotal, imaginaryTotal);
    var sin = imaginaryTotal / totalModule;
    var phaseRad = Math.asin(sin);
    var totalPhase = Math.radiansToDegrees(phaseRad);
    resultPhaseSerie.valueAsNumber = totalPhase.toFixed(2);
    resultModuleSerie.valueAsNumber = totalModule.toFixed(2);
    console.log(resultPhaseSerie.valueAsNumber, resultModuleSerie.valueAsNumber)
}
var sumSerieMoPh = function(){
    var realz1 = Math.cos(phaseSerieZ1.valueAsNumber*Math.PI/180)*moduleSerieZ1.valueAsNumber;
    var imaginaryZ1 = Math.sin(phaseSerieZ1.valueAsNumber*Math.PI/180)*moduleSerieZ1.valueAsNumber;
    var realz2 = Math.cos(phaseSerieZ2.valueAsNumber*Math.PI/180)*moduleSerieZ2.valueAsNumber;
    var imaginaryZ2 = Math.sin(phaseSerieZ2.valueAsNumber*Math.PI/180)*moduleSerieZ2.valueAsNumber;
    var realTotal = realz1 + realz2;
    var imaginaryTotal = imaginaryZ1 + imaginaryZ2;
    var totalModule = Math.hypot(realTotal,imaginaryTotal);
    var sin = imaginaryTotal / totalModule;
    var phaseRad = Math.asin(sin);
    var totalPhase = Math.radiansToDegrees(phaseRad);
    resultPhaseSerie.valueAsNumber = totalPhase.toFixed(2);
    resultModuleSerie.valueAsNumber = totalModule.toFixed(2);
}

// button
serieButton.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(isNaN(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[4,5,6,7])){
        sumSerieReIm();
    } else {
        sumSerieMoPh();
    }
    // if(isNaN(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0,1,2,3])){
    //     sumSerieMoPh();
    // };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
    <title>Calculadoras</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Impedancias serie y paralelo</h1>
    <div class="serieParallel">
        <form action="">
            <div>
                <h3>Suma en serie:</h3>
                <p style="display: block">Conociendo su parte real e imaginaria</p>
                <p style="display: block">Z1 = </p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p>+J</p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p style="display: block">Z2 = </p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p>+J</p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p style="display: block">Conociendo su módulo y ángulo</p>
                <p style="display: block">Z1 = </p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p>con fase</p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p style="display: block">Z2 = </p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p>con fase</p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="calcular" id="serieButton">
            </div>
            <div style="padding-left: 10%">
                <h3 style="margin-bottom: 36px">Resultado:</h3>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p>+J</p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001"><br>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
                <p>con fase</p>
                <input type="number" step="0.001">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
<script src="./JavaScript/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

el problema es que en la parte del boton, si dejo la condicion if de la siguiente forma:

```js
serieButton.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(isNaN(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[4,5,6,7])){
        sumSerieReIm();
    } else {
        sumSerieMoPh();
    }
});
```

y pongo valores en los 4 primeros inputs que seria los valores de real e imaginario, las operaciones se ejecutan y el resultado se muestra, pero si dejo en blanco esos 4 y pongo los valores en los 4 de abajo que serian los valores de modulo y fase, me arroja NaN. pero, si pongo la condicion de la siguiente forma:

```js
serieButton.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(isNaN(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[4,5,6,7])){
        sumSerieReIm();
    } 
    if(isNaN(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0,1,2,3])){
        sumSerieMoPh();
    };
});
```

hace el efecto contrario,y si ejecuta los 4 de abajo.
mi idea con los condicionales es que, si los inputs de real e imaginario tienen un valor, y los de modulo y fase no, que se ejecute la operacion para los primeros, de lo contrario, si los inputs de real e imaginario estan vacios y son los otros los que tienen valor, se ejecute la operacion para estos ultimos.
gracias y perdon por la consulta tan extensa.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que en una consola Javascript, como la de Chrome, hagas las siguientes pruebas:

```
isNaN('')      -> false
isNaN([])      -> false
isNaN(4)       -> false
isNaN('hola')  -> true
```

Por otro lado, si quieres comprobar si es un número, tienes formas mas exhaustivas:

```
!isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n)
```